# How to get the application real name as is shown in Task Mananger?

Tags: c#

I would like to get the application real name as is shown in Task manager process list, for example the process Microsoft Edge. This is my code:

```
// This way the result is "msedge"
var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
uint Id;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out Id);
var Process = Process.GetProcessById((int)Id);
Console.WriteLine(Process.ProcessName); // this print msedge, I don't need this name
```

This is the name I want to:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle?view=net-6.0?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `MainWindowTitle`

```
// This way the result is "msedge"
var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
uint Id;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out Id);
var Process = Process.GetProcessById((int)Id);
Console.WriteLine(Process.MainWindowTitle)
```